# Svelte + Typescript = What to do to make the error go away?

Tags: typescript, svelte

What should I do to make the error disappear? Fix types ? Specify @ts ignore .... what?

---

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eFFN.png)

---

**UPDATE !!!!** **This is a bug! will be fixed on next svelte update**

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible code snippet

Comment: <script lang="ts">
  let w: any;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth={w} />

<h1>{w}</h1>

Comment: Looks like a VS Code plugin is missing, to be honest. Did you get the same error in your terminal when you built?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used svelte, but maybe you just need to add types? Just googling got me this: https://github.com/pyoner/svelte-types

I don't know if it's relevant.

Good luck!

Comment: The types are spelled out, but not all, some are missing